# Applescript will run as script but not application

Tags: macos, applescript

I recently installed Warcraft3:TFT on my Mac using Wine because the Mac version doen't *support* Lion. I wrote a script using Applescript to run the terminal command for Wine and then disable my hot corners so I wouldn't have any issues with navigating the screen.

I wrote the script and it runs fine through Applescript (Compile > Run). The real problem comes in when trying save the script as an application. I save it as an application and then try to run the application (named "Warcraft III - The Frozen Throne") and get this error:

[image: error message on script app execution]

Here is the script itself:

```
set settings1 to {"-", "Desktop", "Start Screen Saver", "Mission Control"}
set settings2 to {"-", "-", "-", "-"}

tell application "Terminal"
     do script "/opt/local/bin/wine ~/.wine/drive_c/Program\\ Files/Warcraft\\ III/war3.exe"
end tell

tell application "System Preferences"
     reveal pane id "com.apple.preference.expose"
     activate
     tell application "System Events"
     tell window "Mission Control" of process "System Preferences"
        click button "Hot Corners…"
        tell sheet 1
            tell group 1
                set theSettings to settings2
                set functionKeys to false
                repeat with k from 1 to 4
                    set theValue to item k of theSettings
                    tell pop up button k
                        if value is not theValue then
                            click
                            click menu item theValue of menu 1
                        end if
                    end tell
                end repeat
            end tell
            click button "OK"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
quit
end tell

display alert "Done playing?" buttons {"Yes"}
set response to button returned of the result
if response is "Yes" then
--Start return to normal settings
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal pane id "com.apple.preference.expose"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        tell window "Mission Control" of process "System Preferences"
            click button "Hot Corners…"
            tell sheet 1
                tell group 1
                    set theSettings to settings1
                    set functionKeys to true
                    repeat with k from 1 to 4
                        set theValue to item k of theSettings
                        tell pop up button k
                            if value is not theValue then
                                click
                                click menu item theValue of menu 1
                            end if
                        end tell
                    end repeat
                end tell
                click button "OK"
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
    quit
end tell
--End return to normal settings

--quit X11 and terminal
tell application "X11"
    quit
end tell
tell application "Terminal"
    quit
end tell
end if
```

This is the first time I have actually written in Applescript so there maybe some sort of error in it that I am not seeing. Thanks in advance for any advice or input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error code has nothing to do directly with your AppleScript. Error –10810 is a Launch Services error code signaling a generic, i.e. unknown error. It seems to get thrown quite often when OS X’ process table runs over. There is a quite thorough [background post on the issue at the X Labs](http://www.thexlab.com/faqs/error-10810.html), complete with step by step instructions to diagnose (and possibly remedy) the issue.

On an OT note, I notice you use GUI scripting to toggle Hot Corners on or off. This is unnecessary: Lion’s *System Events* can script these settings via its *Expose Preferences Suite*, i.e.

```
property hotCornerSettings : {}

to disableHotCorners()
    set hotCorners to {}
    tell application "System Events"
        tell expose preferences
            set end of hotCorners to a reference to bottom left screen corner
            set end of hotCorners to a reference to top left screen corner
            set end of hotCorners to a reference to top right screen corner
            set end of hotCorners to a reference to bottom right screen corner
            repeat with hotCorner in hotCorners
                set hotCornerProps to properties of hotCorner
                set end of hotCornerSettings to {hotCorner, {activity:activity of hotCornerProps, modifiers:modifiers of hotCornerProps}}
                set properties of hotCorner to {activity:none, modifiers:{}}
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell
end disableHotCorners

to restoreHotCorners()
    tell application "System Events"
        tell expose preferences
            repeat with settings in hotCornerSettings
                set properties of item 1 of settings to item 2 of settings
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell
end restoreHotCorners
```

… which spares you the can of worms that is GUI scripting.

Comment: Thanks for the response and the info on the expose in Lion. I'm a bit confused with the code though because it doesn't appear that any of the settings are being stored anywhere. How does it know whether or not it is restoring the correct settings? Again, sorry for my ignorance with Applescript :/

Comment: @Floofer: it’s storing the settings in an AppleScript property in the first line. Properties keep their value after a script is run (they are only re-initialized when the script is re-compiled). The [Apple Script Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_variables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH223-SW10) has all the gory details on properties and their scope.

Comment: @Floofer: ah … just got what your issue is (and sorry for adding another comment, my 5 minute editing window has passed): the script stores your current settings in the above mentioned property – i.e. your hot corner settings when not disabled. This means you don’t have to hard code these into your script, and that the script will always restore to the state it found.

Note I only provided handlers. You will have to add the `do shell script` line, calls to the two handlers provided and the quit commands (which, incidentally, can be written as one-liners, i.e. `tell application "X11" to quit`).

Comment: Alright, I changed the things you suggested and was able to get it running. I actually just copied and pasted my code into XCode and it made a working app, weird? Anyways like I said I changed to use the property rather than open the preferences and it works really slick. It is working great now and everything looks great. Thank you so much for your help! I'd give you a point but don't have enough experience :(